# SabreDAV as client library for external CALDAV server

Tags: php, caldav

Is it possile to use SabreDAV/CalDav as a client libraries to connect external caldav server?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.. SabreDAV is currently just a server..

I have a tiny (barely developed) extension for it that uses SabreDAV and works as a client; If it helps, I can put it somewhere online; but it will be hard for me to give real support for it. Let me know if you need it.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of SabreDAV ^_^